# How to get the value of an input box which doesnot have form tag and submit button in php?

Tags: php

I want to get the value of an input box which doesnot have a form tag and submit button in php

```
<input type="text" id="start-date" name="start" placeholder="Select Date" data-date-format="DD, MM d" class="input-sm form-control"/>

<input type="text" id="end-date" name="end" placeholder="Select Date" data-date-format="DD, MM d" class="input-sm form-control"/><span class="date-text date-return"></span>
```

I want to get the value of these two input boxes and pass into a php variable. It doesnot have a form tag and submit button. How I get the values ?

Comment: you need to use ajax

Comment: ajax+jquery needed

Comment: jquery not needed, ajax therefore yes

Answer (score 1):

You can get value of the textboxes using jquery and pass to any file using ajax:

for getting value using jquery:

```
var startDate = $("#start-date").val();
var endDate = $("#end-date").val();
```

then pass these values to ajax

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php", // path to php file
  data: { start_date: startDate, end_date: endDate } // send required data here
})
.done(function( msg ) {

});
```

Now in php file  you can get these values using:

`$_POST['start_date']` and `$_POST['end_date']`

Comment: <script>

var startDate = $("#start-date").val();
var endDate = $("#end-date").val();

alert(startDate);



</script>

Comment: I have written it like this..but when i am loading the page intially, alert box is showing.after selecting date, it is not displaying the date

Comment: ok.. i got it..Thank you!!.. I needed a help... I have a code for the datepicker for the above two input text boxes.. When I am clicking the first input box and inputting a date from the calendar..the date value get inserted into the first input box as well as the second input box..I dont want the first input box value to be inserted into the second box..

Comment: <script>var dateSelect     = $('#flight-datepicker');var dateDepart    $('#start-date');var dateReturn     = $('#end-date');var spanDepart     = $('.date-depart');var spanReturn     = $('.date-return');var spanDateFormat = 'ddd, MMMM D yyyy';
dateSelect.datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  maxViewMode: 0,
  startDate: "now"
}).on('change', function() {
  var start = $.format.date(dateDepart.datepicker('getDate'), spanDateFormat);
  var end = $.format.date(dateReturn.datepicker('getDate'), spanDateFormat);spanDepart.text(start);spanReturn.text(end);})</script>

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>


 $(document).ready(function(){



$("#start-date").change(function(){
   var startDate = $("#start-date").val();

   alert(startDate);


  });

 $("#end-date").change(function(){
   var endDate = $("#end-date").val();

   alert(endDate);
  });



 });

 </script>
```

I have written the code for getting the values of the input boxes in jquery..but i got the values in two different change function. I dnt know how to pass the values of both the input boxes into the same php file.